# corda implement generic vault query

Tags: java, generics, corda

Trying to create this generic vault query method:

```
        <T extends ContractState> List<StateAndRef<T>> getStatesByLinearId(T stateType, Class<T> cl, String linearId) {
        List<UniqueIdentifier> linearIds = singletonList(UniqueIdentifier.Companion.fromString(linearId));
        QueryCriteria linearCriteriaAll = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(null, linearIds, Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED, null);

        return getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(cl, linearCriteriaAll).getStates();
    }
```

I am not sure how do I get the value for Class. For ex., I am not sure how to call this method:
getStatesByLinearId(IouState.class,??,linearId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```java
IouState state; // Assuming IouState extends or implements ContractState

getStatesByLinearId(state, state.getClass(), linearId);
// or, if you know the class beforehand
getStatesByLinearId(state, IouState.class, linearId);
```

Comment: I don't have the instance of a state yet to try your first option. for second option I am getting an error that says "expect type java.lang.class<T>" if i pass IouState.class

Comment: If you don't have instance, then you need to remove `T stateType` from your list of parameters.

Comment: `expect type java.lang.class<T>` this happens because either `IouState` does not extend `ContractState`, or whatever you passed as first parameter did not have type `IouState`.